# How do i delete Rows once i filter them?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all rows in the datasets, that has the comment 'New'. In order to this i first autofilter 'new' in column E (which worked perfectly) and used the code 'specialcells' to delete it. I used two methods, one was by naming the range and the other was by naming the table. For both codes, i have the the run time error '104'

When i debug, i have the run time error 104 on the line of code below;

-Table
`tableData.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete`

-Range
`tableData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete`

The strange thing is that sometimes it manages to delete the cells, but it will  still show the run-time error 104 pop-up, other times my excel workbook crashes when i run the code.

I am not sure where am i going wrong :/ your help will be really appreciated! thank you

**Below is code with table**

```
Sub Deleterows_Tryagain()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tableData As ListObject
'Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Run_Mailbox")
'Declare table1
Set tableData = ws.ListObjects(1)

'Autofilter Column E,comment "New"
tableData.Range.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="New"

'Delete Rows with comment "New"
tableData.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete

'Show all data
ws.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

**Code indicating the range**

```
Sub Deleterow_NewInvoices()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim tableData As Range

'The Table
Set tableData = Range(Range("A9").End(xlDown), Range("E9"))

'The range to filter the data
Set Rng = Range(Range("A8").End(xlDown), Range("E8"))
'Autofilter Column E,comment "New"
Rng.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="New"

'Delete row
tableData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete


Rng.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after some googling. My code didn't work because my worksheet was protected. In order to correct this;

***Declare your worksheet and unprotect it***

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blabla")

ws.Unprotect
```

***Full code with Table below***

```
'Select worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blabla")

'Done to avoid errors
ws.Unprotect

'Declare table1
Set tableData = ws.ListObjects(1)

'Autofilter Column E,comment "New"
tableData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="New"

'Delete Rows with comment "New"
tableData.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete


End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use something like this.

It doesn't use the autofilter but instead deletes any rows with "New" in column 5 starting at row 9

```
Sub DeleteRowsIf()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
For iCntr = lRow To 9 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = "New" Then
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for your suggestion :) but i have an error for 1004 ` Rows(iCntr).Delete` The rest of the code perfectly recorded the no. of the rows, i think it could be a syntax error im not sure. The message for error 1004 is 'delete method of range class failed'